# Upload file with a text description

Tags: django, upload

I can't manage to upload and save a file with a text value as a description.  I don't understand why: the form and model clearly has the related fields.  When I remove the reference to the text field `tekst` from my view, it does upload and save the file correctly.  FYI: I am using a subdirectory structure basis one of the model fields, which is why there is `def get_upload_to` in my model and `Overig_Beeld.objects.create` in my view, rather than just `upload.save()`.

Model:

```
def get_upload_to(instance, filename):
    return 'bulkafbeeldingen/%s/%s' % (instance.bulknummer, filename)
class Overig_Beeld(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_to)
    bestandnaam = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True)
    upload_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    bulknummer = models.ForeignKey(Bulk, null=True)
    tekst = models.CharField(max_length=512)
```

Form:

```
class Overig_BeeldForm(forms.ModelForm):
    file = forms.FileField()
    tekst = forms.CharField(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Overig_Beeld
        fields = ('file', 'tekst')
```

template:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
      <label for="file">Bestand:</label>
      <input type="file" name="file"/>
      <input type="text" name="tekst"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

View:

```
if request.method=="POST":
    upload = Overig_BeeldForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if upload.is_valid():
        f = request.FILES['file']
        Overig_Beeld.objects.create(file=f, bestandnaam=f.name, bulknummer=bulk, tekst=upload.tekst )
    return redirect(reverse('bulk', args=(bulk.slug,)))
```

error:

```
'Overig_BeeldForm' object has no attribute 'tekst'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uploaded data contains in `cleaned_data` attribute in django form's instance. So

```
text = upload.cleaned_data['tekst']
```

will fix your problem

Comment: Thanks Andrey,  I am not familiar with cleaned_data and I will need to look into it as your suggestion currently throws me an error: `Exception Value: u"Key 'cleaned_data' not found in 'Overig_BeeldForm'"`

Comment: @marckr my bad `cleaned_data` is attribute, not a key. Updated answer

Comment: Thanks so much!  Works perfectly!